# How to use an expression to count intersections in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, field-calculator, intersection, expression

I have a line layer and a point layer. The points intersect the lines. How do I write an expression for the Field Calculator in the line layer which will tell me how many points intersect each line?

I tried `aggregate('point', 'count', intersects(geometry(@parent), $geometry))` but the result of this operation is '11' (total count of all points) for each line.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that is not possible to consider the spatial relation *intersects* between points and lines. 
Use this expression, that creates a temporary small buffer around the line and applied the count of point inside a polygon.

```
aggregate(layer:='point', aggregate:='count', expression:="id", filter:=intersects(geometry(@parent), buffer($geometry,0.01)))
```

To make it working create a "id" field in the point layer and populated it with the field calculator and the expression `$id`.

This will calculate the number of points intersecting the lines as you request. [image: your result]

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're missing a parameter in your expression - it needs a non-null field from your points layer to count (and therefore display), *then* you include the spatial predicate as a filter. Right now, it's interpreting your spatial predicate as the thing to count - and it's going to be the same for the whole layer.

So for example if your points layer has a non-null field called `id`, your expression should look like this.

`aggregate('point', 'count', "id", intersects(geometry(@parent), $geometry))`

Now your expression is counting `id` from the point layer, based on whether it intersects with the parent layer (line).

I have tested this out with both LINESTRING and MULTILINESTRING geometry types in many versions of QGIS 3 and no buffer is required - IIRC in the DE-9IM it is valid to have points and lines intersect.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. As you and Val P said, I didn't realise it needed a field to count. With regards to the buffer, when I tried it on scratch layers it needed a buffer to work, however it didn't need a buffer when I tried it with my actualy data layers (spatialite).

Comment: Good point TeddyTedTed. I created and tested my expression using scratch layers..

Comment: Interesting, I think only the points needs to be an actual layer as I tested the above with a shape file for the points and a scratch layer for the lines